# Symfony 1.4 application "Edit" menu very slow

Tags: php, performance, symfony-1.4

My Symfony 1.4 application "Edit" menu very slow. When I click on edit link it takes almost 2 minutes to response.

I am using the following function in my module's action.class.php file.

```
public function executeNew(sfWebRequest $request) {
    $this->form = $this->configuration->getForm();
    $this->employee_attendance = $this->form->getObject();
}
```

Comment: if you want to check which part of the codebase is taking to long to load, you might wanna use and configure xdebug then check the cachegrind. it should give a graphical representation of your code structure and you can spot which part is the bottleneck

Comment: You can also check what is going on in the dev toolbar (when you use the dev environment). You can check if there are any long running queries or have a look on where the code takes long to execute (it's not as detailed as xdebug's profiler but might be sufficient).

Comment: From dev toolbar I have found that View "Success" for "EmployeeAttendance/edit" 1 81905.27 94 is taking the longest time. Also Partial "EmployeeAttendance/_form" 1 77333.01 88
Partial "EmployeeAttendance/_form_fieldset" 1 77311.52 88
Partial "EmployeeAttendance/_form_field" 8 77303.71 88 are taking time. But I need these forms to be loaded. Can this problem be related to symfony 1.4 and latest php 5.5/ 5.4 version?

Comment: Do you use any select boxes on the form? If so please provide the code you use to define them (unless you're using generated form classes). How many database queries does the dev toolbar show? (the number on the far right, next to a DB icon)

Comment: There are more than 7000 queries. Basically it is searching an entire table. As this application isn't developed by me, I am facing hard time to find how to stop the queries. $shiftinfo = $this->employee_attendance->employee_shift_id; Probably this line gets all of the records. This line is included in executeEdit function of that modules actions.class.php file .How can I minimize it?

Comment: My EmployeeAttendanceForm.class.php has the following code    $this->widgetSchema['employee_shift_id'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineDependentSelect(array(
          'model'=>'EmployeeShiftInfo',
          'depends'=>'employee_id',
          'table_method' => 'getActiveShifts',
          'add_empty'=>'All')); From page source I have found that all shift ids are loaded which is more than 7000

Comment: Ok. So now check the implementation of `__toString` method in the `EmployeeShiftInfo` class. It probably makes a join to some other object. Make sure this join is made in the `EmployeeShiftInfoTable::getActiveShifts` method.

Comment: I have solved the problem by adding unset($this['created_at'], $this['updated_at'], $this['employee_shift_id']) in my lib/form/doctrine/EmployeeAttendanceInput.class.php file . Also removed some unnecessary query code. Thank you very much Michal Trojanowski for your suggessions.

Comment: As we now know what was the culprit I've added an answer which explain the problem. Hopefully some other people will find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a common pitfall when using automatically generated forms in Symfony. When your form has a field which is a foreign key of a related model then a `<select>` element is created for this element. All the possible values of the related values are fetched from the database and populated as objects. Then the `__toString()` method is used on each object to display a user friendly value on the list. If the implementation of this function uses another related object then the relation is read from the database for each object separately.

For example, if you have in your form a field for related object `Shift` and the `__toString` method in the `Shift` class refers to another model, let's say:

```
function __toString()
{
    return sprintf(
        '%s - %s',
        $this->getShiftType()->getName(),
        $this->getName()
    );
}
```

Then the `ShiftType` will be fetched from the database one by one for each `Shift`. If your select lists several thousands shifts you will have the same amount of database queries run each time you open the form (not to mention resources needed to hydrate objects).

There are two things that can be done to solve the problem:

- usually the related object is set in some other way than being chosen by the user so you can just skip the widget altogether. Something like `unset($this['shift_id']);` in your form's `setup` function.
- If you do need the select use a specific table method where you will limit the number of elements retrieved from the DB and/or join with any relevant tables (the `ShiftType` in our example). You can add an option to the widget in your form:

  ```
  $this->widgetSchema['shift_id']->addOption(
      'tableMethod', 
      'yourFunctionRetrievingJoinedTables'
  );
  ```